# Test presence of oxygen > 1%

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

I want to qualitatively test for the presence of oxygen within argon gas. I would like the test to be positive if approx $1\%$ or more is oxygen, but definitely negative if less than $0.1\%$. Anywhere in between is fine—A quantitative test is a bonus. I was thinking of heating iron filings in the gas to deduce it. I'm not sure what apparatus and setup  I would need since heating gas expands, I would like to use ultra low tech equipment. I'm thinking of using water or cooking oil displacement to hold the extra gas, but I don't know if argon would dissolve, or how much oxygen would dissolve. Preferably a nonflammable, certainly nontoxic liquids (or tests).

Comment: What is the idea of this analysis? Do You want to monitor a argon stream? Do You want to check the argon in a cylinder You purchased?

Comment: Yes I would like to test argon in a cylinder I purchased (sorry for delay responding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

http://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/project_ideas/Weather_p004.shtml